Using 'WarmUpConfig' with 'Health Service's'Exercise Client'
I have a question, is it really important to call prepareExercise() or prepareExerciseAsycn() before calling startExercise()?
I am currently learning how to program a fitness tracker app on the Pixel Smartwatch.
Sadly, I am only qualified to test this app and debug it on the Android Studio virtual machine.[T_T]
The app I am working on uses ExerciseClient with DataType.LOCATION and ExerciseType.WALKING.
In my code, I have requested the relevant permissions, and provided GPS | Location in the 'main Settings menu'
I tested it on the Android Studio virtual machine and did not see any signs of crashing?
I wonder if there is any difference when running the app on a real Pixel smartwatch? Have you encountered any problems with it?
Have a nice day everyone.

The benefit of calling prepareExercise() is that it will give the sensors time to warm up. If you're able to test the app out on a real device, I would suggest that, as you'll be able to observe the differences between GPS fix with real-world conditions and the emulator.
Not warming up the sensors will not cause the app to crash, but it means the location will probably not fully register until some point during the exercise, rather than be ready to go at the start.
